# Removing unwanted space between images

Tags: javascript, html, css

My problem is in my navigation bar, which can be found here: http://grupocoral.netai.net/

**There is a space between those images and i want to remove it. How can I do it?**

Javascript Code:

```
function swap(element, image) {
  element.src = image;
}
```

And the html code:

```
<div id="navbar"><a href="index.php"><img src="images/homeover.png"></a>
<a href="membros.php"><img src="images/membros.png" onmouseover="swap(this, 'images/membrosover.png');" onmouseout="swap(this, 'images/membros.png');"></a>
<a href="canticos.php"><img src="images/canticos.png" onmouseover="swap(this, 'images/canticosover.png');" onmouseout="swap(this, 'images/canticos.png');"></a>
<a href="celeb.php"><img src="images/celebracoes.png" onmouseover="swap(this, 'images/celebracoesover.png');" onmouseout="swap(this, 'images/celebracoes.png');"></a>
<a href="contactos.php"><img src="images/contactos.png" onmouseover="swap(this, 'images/contactosover.png');" onmouseout="swap(this, 'images/contactos.png');"></a>
</div>
```

Just in case, navbar CSS code:

```
#navbar{
    width: 1280px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    height: 40px;
    horizontal-align: center;
    padding:inherit;
}
```

**By the way, do you know any other way of making a menu like that without JS?**

Thanks, 
   langel

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's due to the white space in your code. Remove the white space between your links and that should clear it up.

In other words, change your HTML block of navigation to:

```
<div id="navbar"><a href="index.php"><img src="images/homeover.png"></a><a href="membros.php"><img src="images/membros.png" onmouseover="swap(this, 'images/membrosover.png');" onmouseout="swap(this, 'images/membros.png');"></a><a href="canticos.php"><img src="images/canticos.png" onmouseover="swap(this, 'images/canticosover.png');" onmouseout="swap(this, 'images/canticos.png');"></a><a href="celeb.php"><img src="images/celebracoes.png" onmouseover="swap(this, 'images/celebracoesover.png');" onmouseout="swap(this, 'images/celebracoes.png');"></a><a href="contactos.php"><img src="images/contactos.png" onmouseover="swap(this, 'images/contactosover.png');" onmouseout="swap(this, 'images/contactos.png');"></a>    </div>
```

Comment: Or add `font-size: 0;` to #navbar.

Answer (score 3):

Inline elements like these are whitespace dependent, which means that browsers will render some whitespace between them.

to counter this you can either run all your elements together on one line

```
<a href="#">link</a><a href="#">link</a>
```

or block the closing and opening tags

```
<a href="#">
     link</a><a href="#">
</a>
<a href="#">
     link</a><a href="#">
</a>
```

:)

Answer (score 3):

This keeps my code clean and it removes the whitespaces in the code.

```
<a><img src="" /></a><!-- 
--><a><img src="" /></a><!-- 
--><a><img src="" /></a><!-- 
--><a><img src="" /></a>
```

Comment: Hmm, never thought about fighting the dreaded white-space this way. +1 for creativity.

Answer (score 1):

to remove the space just remove the break line between the anchor ex:

and i suggest to use the css without the js :

```
<div id="navbar">
<a class="home" href="#"></a><a href="" class="member"></a>....
</div>
```

CSS :

```
#navbar a{display:inline-block;margin:0;}
#navbar a.member{background:url(images/member.png) no-repeat 0 0}
#navbar a.member:hover{background:url(images/memberhover.png) no-repeat 0 0}
```

Answer (score 1):

You do have an alternative option to your `javascript` image swap.  You can use the `CSS` `:hover` in combination with `background-image`.

dabblet example:
http://dabblet.com/gist/2253898

CSS:

```
#Membros{
    background-image:url('http://grupocoral.netai.net/images/membros.png');
    width:240px;
    height:40px;
}
#Membros:hover {
    background-image:url('http://grupocoral.netai.net/images/membrosover.png');
}
```

HTML

```
<a href="index.php"><div id="Membros"></div></a>
```

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

**By the way, do you know any other way of making a menu like that without JS?**

Yes, here is an [example](http://jsfiddle.net/BDNNd/1/), I've used one of your background image link with 'Home' on it, you should use only one image without any text label on it.

Answer (score 0):

you can also instead of using javascript to change the image source, use :hover css pseudo-class to change the background, it will require you to change the way is made but it will make this menu work even when JS is disabled
[css_pseudo_classes](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_pseudo_classes.asp)

Comment: also for purposes of SEO you may want to restructure your html.
something like:

<ul id="navbar">
 <li><a class="home" href="#home"></li>
...
</ul>