# Why are there spaces between these images?

Tags: html, css

I have an incredibly simple layout, you can see it [here](http://meepmedia.com.au/misc/test.html)

```
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        html, body, div, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, ul, ol, dl, li, dt, dd, p, blockquote, pre, form, fieldset, table, th, td {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }

        ul.mm_sortable_items {
            list-style: none;
        }

        ul.mm_sortable_items li {
                display:inline-block;
                margin: 0;
        }

        ul.mm_sortable_items a {
                display: block;
                width: 100%;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="mm_quicksand_container">            
        <ul class="mm_sortable_items">
            <li class="game_filter_1" id="game_8"><a href="#"><img src="images/itg_0.png"/></a></li>
            <li class="game_filter_1" id="game_9"><a href="#"><img src="images/piu.png"/></a></li>
            <li class="game_filter_2" id="game_10"><a href="#"><img src="images/default.png"/></a></li>
            <li class="game_filter_2 game_filter_3" id="game_11"><a href="#"><img src="images/cam-teng.png"/></a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I want the images to be next to each other with no spaces in between. To the best of my knowledge, what I currently have should do it, but instead there are these gaps between the pictures.

How do I get rid of them?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Removing unwanted space between images](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9948484/removing-unwanted-space-between-images)

Comment: You've got this because of the line-feed between your ´li´ tags... cfr Huangism answer to fix.

Comment: This has been asked many, many times on the internet and here on StackOverflow. You should **always** search before posting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You literally have put spaces between them. If you remove the spaces, the images will come together.

`display:inline-block` displays elements as if they are inline. In other words, the line breaks between your images is being read as white space.

You can solve this using:

`float:left;` rather than `display:inline;` in your CSS

There are workarounds with negative margins, etc. as others have suggested, but this is the usual way to do what you are asking.

Comment: Look again, this is not the case,

Comment: Why is everyone voting this down? It actually was the issue.

Comment: @Michael You're wrong. There is a linebreak and 4 tabs between each `<li>`. That's whitespace, which is collapsed down to 1 space character for display

Comment: No need to declare `display:block;` on top of `float:left;`. And the tabs becoming a space is more a bug than anything, IMO.

Comment: @robooneus is correct. `display:block` is unnecessary - it's just a habit of mine to block floated elements. I have updated the answer.

Comment: I'm marking this as correct as it helped me solve my issue. I didn't end up floating things, but I simply removed the spaces. The reason I didn't want to use float is due to using text-align: center on a container div with these images in it.

Answer (score 3):

Just remove the `display:inline-block` on your list items and float them instead.

```
ul.mm_sortable_items li { 
    float:left;
}
```

Comment: if you float it then there is no need for inline block css

Comment: yea but with floats sometimes you don't always get what you can with inline block

Comment: @Huangism Such as? Is there some functionality missing with floats that the OP needs in the list?

Comment: such as different heights of images and so on and later you might need to clear the floats you know all the small things

Comment: Based on the question, though, floats work perfectly well. And clearing floats is pretty simple.. display:inline-block has its issues as well, as we see here. Floats are generally easier to work with.

Answer (score 2):

add this css

```
.mm_sortable_items {
    font-size: 0;
}
```

Due to spaces between your inline block elements (LI). There are several ways to fix it, you can remove the spaces but it will be hard to read. You could also do negative margin on the li but I personally like the font-size 0 since you have no text anyway

Comment: `inline-block` elements have no margin unless given one by the stylesheet. You mean to say "because there are spaces between the tags in your HTML". Also, the `font-size: 0` is all well and good until the OP wants to put text in their items. I really can't understand why you've got 3 upvotes for this

Comment: if he needs text then just add font-size to the li and problem solved, yes you can put the li side by side but it is hard to read when it comes to maintenance. As I mentioned there are different ways to fix it

Comment: Yes, and your answer describes one of them incompletely. You should edit it instead of adding more detail in the comments

Comment: This is more of a hack or a workaround than a solution. The problem is that there are spaces between the elements and you have suggested making the spaces tiny rather than removing them.

Comment: Twitter Bootstrap uses this method. I'm not saying that makes it good, but it solves the collapsing container problem when using floats. The only issue is having to manually reset the font size on child elements which becomes very inelegant very quickly

Comment: I removed the bit about the auto margin

Comment: Would have to agree with Bojangles and cronoklee, this isn't the most elegant solution. It is more a "this happens to work" than a proper fix.

Comment: Yes to each their own, I just think it will be hard to maintain down the road when other people are looking at an entire line of LIs

Answer (score 1):

You have following

```
ul.mm_sortable_items li {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0;
}
```

Just add

```
float: left;
```

in `ul.mm_sortable_items li`.

Comment: This leads to issues when the container collapses though. Using the `:after` clearfix hack would be a good thing to add

Answer (score 0):

I would've had the reflex of using a [table](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_tables.asp), which would have a single row and a cell for each image (especially since they are of the same size). Then you could make the size of the cell, using [basic CSS](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_table.asp)  the same as the image's one, such that there is no space between them.

Answer (score -1):

I had spaces in my markup to keep it neat. The browser was rendering it as a single space between each image. Whoops.

Answer (score -1):

Add a 
`float:left;` 
rule to the 
`ul.mm_sortable_items li` 
selector.

Answer (score -2):

You have two options in CSS

Option 1:

```
ul.mm_sortable_items li {
margin-right:-4px;
your other CSS here...
```

Option 2:

```
ul.mm_sortable_items li {
float:left;
your other CSS here...
```

Float left is probably considered more of the proper way to do it.

Answer (score -3):

Images in HTML are by default inline elements. What this means is that images are considered equivalent to letters in text. So, there is a space between each image equal to the space between letters. To remove the space between images, you need to use this CSS property on the container of the images:

```
letter-spacing: -4px;
```

That will get your images to stick together.

Comment: You're assuming a space character is exactly 4 pixels wide.